# get everything after non numeric index not including the index in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the series `s` below:

```
s = pd.Series(np.arange(18, 0, -3), list('ABCDEF'))
s

A    18
B    15
C    12
D     9
E     6
F     3
dtype: int32
```

I want to be able to access all elements after index `'D'`

```
E     6
F     3
dtype: int32
```

If I

```
s.loc['D':]
```

I get

```
D     9
E     6
F     3
dtype: int32
```

Not what I wanted.  I could

```
s.loc['D':].iloc[1:]
```

But this doesn't give me a convenient way to assign back to the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** thanks to @Alex he has reminded that indices are not always monotonically increasing:

```
In [85]: s
Out[85]:
F    18
B    15
D    12
A     9
C     6
E     3
dtype: int32

In [86]: s.iloc[s.index.get_loc('D') + 1:]
Out[86]:
A    9
C    6
E    3
dtype: int32
```

try this:

```
In [57]: s[s.index > 'D']
Out[57]:
E    6
F    3
dtype: int32
```

or using indexers:

```
In [59]: s.ix[s.index > 'D'] = 100

In [60]: s
Out[60]:
A     18
B     15
C     12
D      9
E    100
F    100
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 3):

See MaxU's answer if you know that index values are monotonically increasing. Otherwise...

```
m = s.index == 'D'
idx = m.argmax() if m.any() else len(m)
s.iloc[idx + 1:] = 0
```